# Need to be able to use UTF-8 playlists

Tags: music-player

## DISCLAIMER

I am aware that asking after an app to accomplish a task is generally off-topic here. If the solution to this question involves an app that's great, but this is mostly about unicode-aware playlists on Android.

Without further ado...

I regularly use OS X (iTunes) at home, linux at work, and an android phone. I would like to be able to share playlists across devices, and even wrote a little command line utility to convert iTunes XML playlists to m3u8/xspf and correct the file paths depending on the target machine.

But there's a couple of catches:

1. My music collection is fairly large (~27 GB) and I have yet to find any syncing software (e.g. doubletwist) that doesn't keel over and die. So I need to keep this stuff in sync manually, no automagic (unless it actually works).
2. I have a number of files who's names contain Spanish characters, Norwegian characters, or Japanese kanji, so the playlist has to be in a format that recognizes UTF characters (i.e. m3u8 over m3u).
3. I could care less about what format gets used, assuming it has a spec I am more than willing to write code to convert to it.

My stuff I've already done works fine for linux (VLC media player does fine), but VLC android doesn't seem to deal with unicode-aware playlists, nor does doubletwist cloud player.

Searching around the internet has found things mostly related to streaming lists (I don't care about streaming at all), usually pertain to video (I only care about music), or are about libraries one would use *writing* an android music player (which I'd prefer to avoid). I also see alot of questions here on android SE about timestamps, play counts, and other bells and whistles I don't really care about, I just want my playlists to work.

Does anyone know any way (player, syncher, whatever) to get unicode-aware music playlists working on android reading the local filesystem (which AFAIK *is* unicode-aware)?

*PS if it matters, HTC M8 running Marshmellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that vlc and doubletwist cloud player can read unicode in `.m3u` file extensions just fine (even though they theoretically shouldn't), but only if the strings have been normalized to not use the combining character codes for inflections.